# laravel вложенный запрос

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Подскажите , как можно оптимизировать запрос:

```
select * from (select * from `bron` where DATE('2015-12-14') between `start` and `end`)t1 where nomer = '2';
```

и реализовать с помощью конструктора

```
$bron_between2 = DB::table('bron')
->select(DB::raw("DATE('$date') between start and end"))
->where('nomer', $nomer)->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос решен.

```
    $bron_between= DB::table('bron')
    ->whereRaw("DATE('$date') between start and end")
    ->where('nomer', '=', $nomer->id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Можно  еще проще
     $bron_start= DB::table('brons')
                    ->where('nomer',$nomer->id)
                    ->where( 'start' , '<=', $j)
                    ->where('end' , '>=', $j)
                    ->get();